# Plotting mean and standard error of mean from linear regression

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I've run a multiple linear regression where `pred_acc` is the dependent continuous variable and `emotion_pred` and `emotion_target` are two dummy coded independent variables with 0 and 1. Furthermore I am interested in the interaction between the two independent variables.

```
model <- lm(predic_acc ~ emotion_pred * emotion_target, data = data_almost_final) 
summary(model)

    Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.66049 -0.19522  0.01235  0.19213  0.67284 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  0.97222    0.06737  14.432  < 2e-16 ***
emotion_pred                 0.45988    0.09527   4.827 8.19e-06 ***
emotion_target               0.24383    0.09527   2.559 0.012719 *  
emotion_pred:emotion_target -0.47840    0.13474  -3.551 0.000703 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2858 on 68 degrees of freedom
  (1224 Beobachtungen als fehlend gelöscht)
Multiple R-squared:  0.2555,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2227 
F-statistic: 7.781 on 3 and 68 DF,  p-value: 0.0001536
```

In case some context is needed: I did a survey where couples had to predict their partners preferences. The predictor individual was either in emotion state 0 or 1 (emotion_pred) and the target individual was either in emotion state 0 or 1 (emotion_target). Accordingly, there are four combinations.

Now I want to plot the regression with the means of each combination of the independent variables (0,1; 1,0; 1,1; 0,0) and add an error bar with the standard error of the means. I have literally no idea at all how to do this. Anyone can help me with this?

Here's an extraction from my data:

```
     pred_acc  emotion_pred  emotion_target
1  1.0000000              1               0
2  1.2222222              0               1
3  0.7777778              0               0
4  1.1111111              1               1
5  1.3888889              1               1
```

[Sketch of how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHux0.jpg)

Comment: What you want is called an 'interaction plot'.  The `emmip` function in the `emmeans` package does exactly this, I'm sure there are others.  If you add some data to your question to make it reproducible then people can give you complete answers.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva thanks for your reply. I've added some example data as well as the results of the regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `emmip` from the `emmeans` library:

```
model <- lm(data=d2, pred_acc ~ emotion_pred*emotion_target)

emmip(model, emotion_pred ~ emotion_target, CIs = TRUE, style = "factor")
```

[image]

If you want more control over the image or just to get the values you can use the `emmeans` function directly:

```
> emmeans(model , ~ emotion_pred * emotion_target )

 emotion_pred emotion_target emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
            0              0  0.778 0.196  1   -1.718     3.27
            1              0  1.000 0.196  1   -1.496     3.50
            0              1  1.222 0.196  1   -1.274     3.72
            1              1  1.250 0.139  1   -0.515     3.01
```

Then you can use ggplot on this dataframe to make whatever graph you like.

Comment: I have one more question regarding the results from emmeans. I received the same SE for all four conditions, which seems a bit odd to me. When I calculated SE by hand I received different results. Do you know what could be the problem? I also calculated the means by hand and those were equivalent to the column "emmean".
EDIT: my data set is balanced

Comment: If your data is balanced (equal numbers for each predictor combination) then you will get the same SE for all of the marginal means, which is correct.  Under the linear regression model, there is only one standard deviation (this is what R calls "residual standard error") and it is assumed to be common across all predictor levels.  In which case the sampling error of each mean hence its standard error should be the same.

Comment: When you use a linear model like this, equality of variances across groups is one of the assumptions that you make.  If there is an enormous difference in variances across groups then you should rethink your model.

Comment: Another point - if your data is balanced this would suggest the emotional states were manipulated experimentally?   If you have the same couples being repeated in different conditions then you would have to take this into account in your analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, helped me a lot. I indeed have a balanced sample and the emotional states were induced as part of a study. However, every individual was induced only one emotional state. I checked for homoscedasticity and noticed my sample has heteroskedasticity. Can I use vcov() instead for my model. E.g. coeftest(model, vcov = vcovHC(model, type = "HC3"))? I think that would be the right approch but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: To be honest, a linear regression to model a probability is likely to be problematic.  Not least because you don't want responses or intervals >1 or <0, but also the likely heteroskedisticity. You could be better off using a binomial regression or something like that, where each response is the number of successes and the number of trials.  I don't know about coeftest.  This isn't really a discussion for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you! Will have a look at binominal regression. It's my first time on stackoverflow, did not know that but will keep it in mind.

Comment: No problem.  I'm not saying linear modelling doesn't work here,  just be aware of the potential issue.  SO is for programming problems so your original question was fine; when we get into statistics conversations a different forum is probably best.  Good luck anyway.